# How to extract specific string from whole string?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have following strings :

```
String? hello = "(1.2,1.5 | 5)"
String? hi = "(2.3,3.2 | 9)"
```

Now I want to get

```
var newhello1 = 1.2,1.5
var newhello2 = 5
```

and

```
var newhi1 = 2.3,3.2
var newhi2 = 9
```

How to extract those text from that entire strings?

Comment: `newhello1` will be a list?

Comment: No. It will be a string only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `indexOf` function combined with the `substring` to get the substrings as follows

```
var newhello1 = hello.substring(hello.indexOf('(') + 1, hello.indexOf('|')).trim(); //Use Trim() to get rid of any extra spaces
var newhello2 = hello.substring(hello.indexOf('|') + 1,hello.indexOf(')')).trim();
print(newhello1); //1.2,1.5
print(newhello2); //5
```

Comment: It will be a string only

Comment: okay, I'll edit the answer to keep the relevant part only.

Answer (score 0):

```dart
List<String> myformatter(String? data) {
  if (data == null) return [];
  List<String> ls = data.split("|");

  for (int i = 0; i < ls.length; i++) {
    ls[i] = ls[i].replaceAll("(", "").replaceAll(")", "").trim();
  }
  return ls;
}

main() {
  String? hello = "(1.2,1.5 | 5)";
  String? hi = "(2.3,3.2 | 9)";

  final helloX = myformatter(hello);

  print(helloX[0]); //1.2,1.5 
  print(helloX[1]); //5

  final hiX = myformatter(hi);
  print(hiX[0]); //2.3,3.2 
  print(hiX[1]); //9
}
```